# Nginx configuration for server-side rendering of static assets, a node request handler, and index.html fallback

Tags: nginx

I want to serve an app that's built with webpack and therefore can always be served statically, but I want to put a node server (with JSDOM) that'll pre-render the HTML for each request. The node server should only be hit for requests that cannot be served statically, and if the server is taken out these requests should then be redirected to serve the static `index.html`

So, nginx should do the following in this order:

1. Serve all asset files (app.js,css,etc) **except** index.html statically
2. Proxy all other requests (/users,/products/,etc) to node app
3. If above proxy fails, serve `index.js` for all those requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using this which seems to be working

```
server {
  root /my-app;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @node;
  }

  location @node {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    error_page 502 = @static;
  }

  location @static {
    try_files $uri /index.html $uri;
  }
}
```